# SVG <animate> to css

Tags: css, svg

I've learned about the `<animate>` attribute, and created a little animation of an elastic line. Now I'm trying to convert this to css to have more control : I'd like to trigger the animation only when hovering the line element, but I can't figure out how..

Here is a [Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7tL5osr0/2/)

And here is my html / svg code :

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="cntr" id="grid">
      <defs>
        <style>
          path {
            stroke: red;
            stroke-width: .2;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            fill: none;
          }
        </style>
      </defs> 
      <g class="drawing">
        <g class="path-wrap">
          <path d="M 30,40 Q 50,40 70,40">
            <animate
              attributeName="d"
              dur="1.5s"
              begin="1s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              values="M 30,40
                      Q 50,40 70,40; 

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,50 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,35 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,45 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,38 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,42 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,39 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,41 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;
                      
                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;"
              fill="freeze"
            />          
          </path>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to convert `<animate>` attributes easily? Or is it impossible?

Comment: Only Chrome supports CSS animation of path d attributes.

Comment: check this https://medium.com/finnovate-io/convert-your-svg-animations-to-css-animations-now-85f45dc68367

Answer (score 2):

As @Robert Longson commented: `Only Chrome supports CSS animation of path d attributes`

If you want to flexibly control `SVG animate` well as , then you have an equally powerful set of attributes and parameters` as in css animation.
For example, if you need to implement the beginning and end of an animation when you hover and move the mouse cursor out, then need to write:

```
begin="grid.mouseover"
end="grid.mouseout"
```

While the cursor is within the boundaries of the svg canvas, animation continues when you leave the svg animation ends

```html
<svg id="grid" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30%" height="30%" viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="cntr" style="border:1px solid gray;"

>
      <defs>
        <style>
          path {
            stroke: red;
            stroke-width: 1;
            stroke-linecap: round;
            fill: none;
          }
        </style>
      </defs> 
      <g class="drawing">
        <g class="path-wrap">
          <path d="M 30,40 Q 50,40 70,40">
            <animate
              attributeName="d"
              dur="1.5s"
              begin="grid.mouseover"
     end="grid.mouseout"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
              values="M 30,40
                      Q 50,40 70,40; 

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,50 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,35 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,45 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,38 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,42 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,39 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,41 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 50,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 60,40 70,40;

                      M 30,40
                      Q 40,40 70,40;"
              fill="freeze"
            />          
          </path>
        </g>
      </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: So i've tried this but i doesn't give enough control over the events.. What i finally did is converting the `<animate>` into css and added just a touch of javascript so the animation continues to the end even when the element isn't hovered anymore. But the issue is that it's not very reactive.. If you hover over too quickly, the animation doesn't launch. I'd like to be able to smoothly restart the animation if you hover it twice or more. Here is what i have right now : https://jsfiddle.net/o64aymt8/1/

Comment: @Perdixo Do you want your option not to be cross-browser? Since the animation of the `d` attribute only works in Chrome. Why are you not happy with my version that works reliably and quickly in Firefox and Chrome?  If you need a solution with JS, then it would be nice to ask a new question and accept this as a solution

Answer (score 1):

On the "begin" property, if you change it to `begin="mouseover"`, it should work.

```
                 attributeName="d"
                 dur="1.5s"
                 begin="mouseover"
...
```